# Python boost to-Python converter for class already registered second conversion method ignored

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, converters

I have next class (it was simplified):

```
class Value
{
    public:

    Value();
    ~Value();

    void setValue(int value);
    void setValue(double value);
}
```

I have python boost module:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/map_indexing_suite.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(py_classes) 
{
    typedef std::vector<Value> VectorClass;

    boost::python::type_info infoVectorValue = boost::python::type_id<VectorClass>();

    const boost::python::converter::registration* regVectorValue = boost::python::converter::registry::query(infoVectorValue);

    if (regVectorValue == NULL || (*regVectorValue).m_to_python == NULL) {
        class_<VectorClass>("std_vector_value")
            .def(vector_indexing_suite<VectorClass>());
    }
}
```

Python script is called from dll library and uses container from pyd `py_classes`. When dll-library is called first time `std_vector_value` type is used without any problems.
When I reload dll-library inside executable I get next warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for class
boost::python::detail::container_element<class std::vector<class Value,class std::allocator<class Value> >,
unsigned __int64,class boost::python::detail::final_vector_derived_policies
<class std::vector<class Value,
class std::allocator<class Value> >,0> > 
already registered; second conversion method ignored.
return f(*args, **kwds)
```

So, it means:

- When dll-library is loaded first time, to-python converter is registered normally and python script can use `std_vector_value` type.
- When dll-library is reloaded (`FreeLibrary` and `LoadLibrary` functions), to-python converter trying to register one more time and checking if it was registered says that it has been already registered, but I can't use `std_vector_value` type from python.

And this situation appears only for container classes (if I use `std::vector` or `std::map` - generally if I use `vector_indexing_suite` or `map_indexing_suite`), for class Value this warning doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was next: boost python was loaded from one exe-process, but by different DLL-libraries. It means I had 3 DLL-libraries that executed python scripts. 
Python boost types worked without any problem until DLL-libraries were reloaded (calling FreeLibrary and LoadLibrary inside process without process relaunching).
Python boost has static variable `register` (register is the name of this variable) stores references to python boost types.
When executable is launched, references to types are added to the static variable `register`.
So, this check works normally:

```
boost::python::type_info infoVectorValue = boost::python::type_id<VectorClass>();
const boost::python::converter::registration* regVectorValue = boost::python::converter::registry::query(infoVectorValue);
if (regVectorValue == NULL || (*regVectorValue).m_to_python == NULL) {
```

But when DLL-libraries are unloaded, references to these python boost types are left inside the static variable `register` and they lead to DLL-library addresses that were freed. It means when library is loaded again, types checking gets reference for needed type (`VectorClass` in my example) without problems, but this reference has already broken.

So, the solution for this problem is to link boost python library statically to each DLL-library - each DLL-library has it's own static variable `register` and boost python types
references are created for each DLL-library and when DLL-library is unloaded, `register` variable is destroyed for this DLL.